# PHP PDO unable to insert the data in MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, forms, pdo, insert, registration

I am learning PHP.using XAMPPlocal server to test. Need help below
            when I enter the details and  click register in the form, I just see a blank page with the action.php link.
*Code for action.php is below:*

```
include 'config.php';
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
            if(isset($_POST['register'])){
                require 'config.php';
                $first_name = !empty($_POST['fname']) ? trim($_POST['fname']) : null;
                $last_name = !empty($_POST['lname']) ? trim($_POST['lname']) : null;
                $user_name = !empty($_POST['uname']) ? trim($_POST['uname']) : null;
                $pass = !empty($_POST['upass']) ? trim($_POST['upass']) : null;
                $user_email = !empty($_POST['umail']) ? trim($_POST['umail']) : null;
                $sql = "INSERT INTO ams_users (id, firstname, lastname, username, password, email) 
                                      VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

                $result = $stmt->execute(0,$first_name, $last_name, $user_name, $pass, $user_email);
                if($result){
                    echo 'Thank you for registering';
                }else{
                    echo 'sorry';
                    }
                }enter code here
```

code for register.php form below:

```
<div class="reg-form">
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <form action="action.php" method="POST">
            <p><label>First Name* :</label> 
            <input id="firstname" type="text" name="fname" /></p>
            <p><label>Last Name* :</label> 
            <input id="lasttname" type="text" name="lname" /></p>

            <p><label>User Name* : </label>
            <input id="username" type="text" name="uname" /></p>

             <p><label>Password: </label>
             <input id="password" type="password" name="upass" /></p>
             <p><label>E-Mail: </label>
             <input id="e-mail" type="e-mail" name="umail"/></p>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="register" />
            </form>
        </div>
```

MySQL table has 5 entries: id (autoincrement, firstname, lastname,username,password, and email.

```
please help where I am going wrong.
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Also why is `enter code here` in your source? That is not valid PHP so you may have a syntax error here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `execute()` takes an array of parameters not directly like you did.
- You have less question marks then parameter
- If you make `id` AUTOINCREMENTED then you can omit it from your query

So it becomes:

```
INSERT INTO ams_users (firstname, lastname, username, password, email) 
VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)
```

Then you execute:

```
$result = $stmt->execute(array($first_name, 
                               $last_name, 
                               $user_name, 
                               $pass, 
                               $user_email)
                 );
```

Or:

```
INSERT INTO ams_users (id,firstname, lastname, username, password, email) 
VALUES('',?,?,?,?,?)
```

The problem is you should have gotten the error, so make sure it is turned on:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: The error statements is in my config.php file. Which is working fine when I dont use the array method.

Comment: I will try meda's method todat and let you know if still I have issues. Thanks

Comment: Hi I checked I was using wrong connection variable $pdo instead of $db. Thats the reason no errors were shown.

Comment: i have another issue, I have defined id as auto increment in the table structure. But when the PDO exception / errors are thrown, the id still increment without any successful insert operation. How do I ensure that id is incremented auto only on a successful insert into the DB and not at every connection tries???